# Getting an error: Admin.js:14 POST http://localhost:3009/api/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Why am i getting an Admin.js:14  POST http://localhost:3009/api/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

this is the error that I'm getting when trying to submit my form on the front end to the backend
my port on the backend is set to 3009 and my endpoint when fetching the 3009 is localhost:3009/api/upload on the backend
title, genre, bpm, key, and duration

Here is the code to Admin.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Admin = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
    const [bpm, setBpm] = useState("");
    const [key, setKey] = useState("");
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        fetch("http://localhost:3009/api/upload", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title,
                genre,
                bpm,
                key,
                duration
            })
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-[100%] h-[100vh]">
            <p className="mb-[40px]">Upload Song</p>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col w-[350px] gap-[10px]">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Genre" onChange={(e) => setGenre(e.target.vaue)} />
                <input type="number" placeholder="BPM" onChange={(e) => setBpm(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Key" onChange={(e) => setKey(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Duration" onChange={(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)} />
                <button className="bg-red-500" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin
```

Here is the code to uploadSong.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const UploadSongSchema = require("../models/uploadSong");

router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
    const {
        title,
        genre,
        bpm,
        key,
        duration,
    } = req.body;

    const song = new UploadSongSchema({
        title,
        genre,
        bpm,
        key,
        duration,
    });
    try {
        await song.save();
        res.status(201).send(song);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Server error");
    }
})


module.exports = router;







Here is the code to index.js
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
const uploadRoute = require("./routes/uploadSong");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 3009;

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true.value,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to DB")
})

app.use("/api", uploadRoute);

app.listen(3009, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

i have tried refractor my kind and everything and keep getting different errors

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you stringified the body on the client but on the server you didn't parse it.

Before destructing, make sure you parse the string somehow:

```
const {
    title,
    genre,
    bpm,
    key,
    duration,
} = JSON.parse(req.body);
```